# Can't I overload the input operator to input an array of characters (C-style string), that is a member variable of my class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Take the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Input
 {
    int m_int;
    double m_doub;
    char* m_char;

public:
    Input(int integer, double floating, char* character)
    {
        m_int = integer;
        m_doub = floating;
        m_char = character;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream &ope, Input &obj);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &ope, Input &obj);

    int ret_int(){return m_int;}
    double ret_doub(){return m_doub;}
    char* ret_char(){return m_char;}
};

istream& operator >> (istream &ope, Input &obj)
{
    ope >> obj.m_int;
    ope >> obj.m_doub;
    ope >> obj.m_char;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream &ope, Input &obj)
{
    ope << obj.m_int;
    ope << obj.m_doub;
    ope << obj.m_char;
}

int main()
{
    Input var(51, 56.2, "Avneet");

    std::cin >> var;
    std::cout << var;
    return 0;
}
```

The program is okay until I input the string through the overloaded operator.
ope >> obj.m_int accepted, ope >> obj.m_doub accepted, ope >> obj.m_char program crashed???

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You don't get any warnings or errors when you don't return the streams from the operators?

Comment: I get only one warning from the compiler that conversion of string("Avneet") to C-style string shouldn't be done that way.

Answer (score 3):

The problem starts here

```
Input var(51, 56.2, "Avneet");
```

where you initialize the `char*` pointer in `Input` with a string literal.

The input operation `ope >> obj.m_char` will then attempt to store the input in the literal. Crash!

Would work much better with a `std::string` member.

Comment: Okay, so how can I access the variable m_char instead of literal inside operator>>? Is there a way?

Comment: You have to allocate space to store the input, which might be hard if you don't know how large it is going to be. Using a `std::string` instead of a `char*` would help you with that, as the string will resize itself as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your overloaded functions must return something

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream &ope, Input &obj);
```

more precisely `istream&`

It's strange that you don't have a compile error anyway...

Comment: I don't know if there should be an error or warning (using Code::Blocks).

Comment: Anyway, one error is that you need to return something from inside your functions. What do you want to accomplish with that `std::cin >> var`?

Comment: I want to input all the members in that class for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
strcpy(m_char, character);
```

to instead of

```
m_char = character;
```

cannot directly assign pointer.

Comment: That causes the program to crash earlier :-(